# Attaching a scroll from one div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've two divs, positioned one over the other (as shown in the image)
DIV 2 holds an image, and does not have any content to be scrolled.
I want to enable the user to continue scrolling DIV 1, even when the cursor is within the boundaries of DIV 2.

[image]

Comment: #div2 { overflow: hidden; }

Comment: That makes the scrolling freeze in DIV2 but does not sync it onto DIV1

Comment: if you dont have anything to do with the div2 then use #div2 { pointer-events: none; }

Comment: Beautiful. Worked like a charm. Thanks !!

Comment: happy to hear that it worked for you.